# Magento 2 how we can apply those condition in the frontend?

Tags: magento2, conditions-serialized

I was add a condition action in custom module admin form in magento 2

[image]

I used this blog to create a condition action: https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/

Database:

[image]

how we can apply those saved condition in the frontend?

Comment: where you want to apply that condition?

Comment: i need to above condition  will applied  to restrict payment method,  Reference extension https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-payment-restrictions.html

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q0f3uv

Comment: Well, It's long process to do that. It would be better to solve your question in small parts.

Comment: i  was completed every part in the extension except the conditions to be met, based on cart attributes, customer attributes

Comment: So, you mean you just want to know how to fetch condition_serialized value in your file?

Comment: ya i need how to fetch condition_serialized value and how to validate in frontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101347/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-divya-sekar).

Comment: Is it same as like you want?

Comment: Can you pls check in chat room?

Comment: @rohan hapani can you please accept the github invitation

Comment: okay...........

Comment: It's returns 404

Comment: can please check your github https://prnt.sc/q1q5u8

Comment: It's outdated. Can you pls send on this? https://github.com/RHapani

Comment: can please tell me how to send by above link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101459/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-divya-sekar).

Comment: @divyasekar, You got any solution here ?

Comment: no, some answers getting  a fatal error

Comment: @divyasekar - I have installed your module and try to access payment restrictions grid, it returns to dashboard with `Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.` this error message.

Comment: @Ranganathan l please do logout after login into admin

Comment: Nono....I found and fixed the issue....What is the magento version you tried?

Comment: in magento 2.1.3 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any rule-model could be used this way:

```
$ruleModel->validate($validationModel);
```

But your rule model must extend the `\Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel` class and object which you will validate must have desired data (subtotal in your case, so I suppose it will be instance of `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address`).

So, an example will be looking like this:

```
$address = $block->getAddress(); // or $quote->getAddress();
$rules = $block->getRules(); // load all availabel rules from DB
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if ($rule->validate($address)) {
        echo __('Pass conditions of the rule %1', $rule->getId());
    } else {
        echo __('Missed rule %1', $rule->getId());
    }
}
```

The `$rule->validate()` will call this code:

```
/**
 * Validate rule conditions to determine if rule can run
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $object
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
{
    return $this->getConditions()->validate($object);
}
```

Comment: It reflects a  `Fatal error: call to  a member function validate() on string`

Comment: @divyasekar Check why your `$rule` is a string. It must be instance of `\Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel` How you load a rules?

Comment: Thank you so much @Siarhey Uchukhlebau  finally i done it by  your way

Comment: @divyasekar I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: how to validate a  condition rules based on  product attributes  https://prnt.sc/q8rm1n can you please help me resolve this

Comment: @divyasekar it must be validated as usual but your model must have that attributes (values).

Comment: here i explained in detail https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298484/magento-2-validate-a-condition-rules-based-on-product-attribute can please  help me

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Finally i found out a way for validate a  condition by **@Siarhey Uchukhlebau** answer

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $_pageFactory;
     protected $cart;
     protected $quoteFactory;
     Protected $rule;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $quoteFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Rule $rule
   )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->rule = $rule;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

    // Testing execution 

        $quoteId = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();
        $quoteAddress = $this->quoteFactory->getCollection();
        $rules = $this->rule->getCollection();
        $validate =array();

        foreach ($quoteAddress as $address):
            if( $quoteId == $address['quote_id']):
                $addressId = $address['address_id'];
            endif;    
        endforeach;
        foreach($rules as $rule):
           $quote = $this->quoteFactory->load($addressId);
           $validate = $rule->validate($quote);
        endforeach;
        return  $validate;
    }
    public function validate(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
    {
        return $this->getConditions()->validate($object);
    }

}
```

> Vendor/Module/Model/Rule.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor/Module\Model;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;
/**
 * Class Rule
 * @package Vendor\Module\Model
 *
 * @method int|null getRuleId()
 * @method Rule setRuleId(int $id)
 */
class Rule extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_module';
    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getRule() in this case
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory */
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory */
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    /**
     * Store already validated addresses and validation results
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
     \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
     \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
       \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Set resource model and Id field name
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }
    /**
     * Get rule condition combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
     */
      public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition product combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine
     */
    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condProdCombineF->create();
    }
    /**
     * Check cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }
    /**
     * Set validation result for specific address to results cache
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @param bool $validationResult
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }
    /**
     * Return id for address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @divyasekar, Rajan here, can you please let me know if you have added a condition like subtotal greater than 100 then it will apply on your rule so in your code where is that code on which it will take your rule condition?

Comment: i didn't get you rajan, let me please clarify me  if you asking about  how to validate a condition rule?  (or)  where going to validate a condition rule?

Comment: i was take rule  from  model file and validate a condition on (controller or observer) file that you required.  let see my edited post @rajan

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, You need to convert serialize value into unserialize form. For that, Use this below code :

```
protected $salesRuleFactory;
protected $serializer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $salesRuleFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
){
    $this->salesRuleFactory = $salesRuleFactory;
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
}


public function yourFunction()
{   
    $ruleId = 1;
    $rule = $this->salesRuleFactory->create()->load($ruleId);
    print_r($this->serializer->unserialize($rule->getConditionsSerialized()));
}
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
    [attribute] => 
    [operator] => 
    [value] => 1
    [is_value_processed] => 
    [aggregator] => all
    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found
                    [attribute] => 
                    [operator] => 
                    [value] => 1
                    [is_value_processed] => 
                    [aggregator] => all
                    [conditions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product
                                    [attribute] => category_ids
                                    [operator] => ()
                                    [value] => 25,16
                                    [is_value_processed] => 
                                    [attribute_scope] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Then, you can get value from this array based on your requirements.

Comment: In  magento 2.1.3 ver, shows a error of `class magento\framework\serialize\serializer\json does not exist`

Comment: Oh....!! Strange ..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$product_id = '1';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer_group = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
$rules = $objectManager->create('\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory')->create()->getCollection();
$rules->setValidationFilter(1, $customer_group);
$rules->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
    $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $item->setProduct($product);
    $validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($item);
    // Validate rule for product
    if ($validate) {
        $dataToEncode = $rule->getConditionsSerialized();
        $conditions = $this->json->unserialize($dataToEncode);
        $countCondition = count($conditions);
        if ($countCondition >= 7) {
            // Write your code based on $conditions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i was get a fatal error https://prnt.sc/q1qeu3

Comment: Tru `$rule->validate($item);` or else add your controller code in question.

Comment: above function works for catalog rule  but i need to validate cart details like  subtotal, shipping country etc @Dhaduk Mitesh its there any possible ways to check a  cart details

Comment: You just load your cart product here in payment page. And if it is validate for your item then you can do anything in `if ($validate)`.

Comment: If you have your custom rule then you can get rule from custom model and set in `$rules`.

Comment: Can please help me to solve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298484/magento-2-validate-a-condition-rules-based-on-product-attribute